# Python UnitTest - How can I access subTests messages without having to write them manually?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, logging

A little bit of context: I am using Python and Selenium for QA Web Automation and I am using the Page Object Model pattern. 
I am currently in the process of making the logger part of the system, and I want to make the code more efficient, without
having to write a lot of dublicate code. I checked the docs for subTests, but can't find anything in particular and this is the reason I am here. So I am wondering if there is a way to access this part of the code (so I don't have to
write each logger message each time, which is not very practical):

```
  class TestScenario(unittest.TestCase):

      .... # set Up class

      def logger(self,info):
          logger.error(f"Error happened at {info}")

      def test_method(self):

          with self.subTest("MESSAGE"):---------------------------------------------                                     
                                                                                   |
              try:                                                                 |
                  ... something                                                    |
              except AssertionError:                                               | 
                  self.logger(#Is there a way to access subTest msg parameter?) <---
                  raise

          .... other subTests which will follow the same pattern
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why are you doing a `try... except AssertionError`? Unittest is managing this. The log of unittest are not enough for you?

Comment: @ndclt Because I want to do some stuff if I catch an error, I have skipped most of the code (and this is a test scenario on a testing in a web browser) - but the current plan is to do a screenshot on test failure (self.save_screenshot("{MESSAGE}.png"} and the logger thing. I just showed the logger as an example. I will also probably add my own custom exception with more specific information.

Comment: `subTest` arguments are to distinguish and identify subtest not to collect results. And, yeah, lil bit wierd way to use unittest.

Comment: @Poolka it's because I have to make a testing scenario. User logs in, does something, logs out. If I use subtests, i can test each individual action of the user, and it also asserts that everything goes in order (because he can only access something after he logs in for example), which assures no code duplication. This was the reason I started using subTests, so far is the most efficient way I found out.

Comment: And I want to access the arguments to identify the tests in the logger, screenshot name, etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do `self.logger(self._subtest._message)` to get the message.

Beware, you are accessing internals variable of unittest thus this code can be broken in the next release of python without warning.

Answer (score 1):

Possible approach:

```
class Message:
    def __init__(self, message=''):
        self.message = message
    def __str__(self):
        return self.message

# separate message for every subtest or one message continually modified between subtests
msg = Message('qwe')

...
with self.subTest(msg=msg):
    msg.message = 'asd'  # access or modify
    self.assertTrue(True)
...
```

Or you may create attribute `message` in the `setUp` method of the test and use it to pass message into `subTest` and access/modify when you need.